# How do I put padding outside an image border?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to put some padding above an image so it's not directly against the text I have up there. The image has a border on it, and when I try to put the padding above it leaves the top part of the image's border up there. So there is an unwanted space above the image between the border. Can anyone help me? This is the css I am using:

```css
img {
  padding-top: 28px;
  border:5px solid #e26b34;
}
```

Comment: Why not use margin instead of padding?

Comment: @user500665 I assume because he want to have a space between actual image and border

Comment: @vicodin I think he is just trying to use padding as margin. But if it as you say then he can use both.

Comment: @user500665 I agree, we need clarification, probably OP confuses `margin` and `padding`

Comment: @user500665 I did not think of that. Thanks! My apologies if that seemed like a stupid question, I am very new to coding and html/css.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) like below. Margin does basically the same thing as paddding, except padding is inside the element (inside the border) while margin is outside the element (outside the border).

You can find more about margin and padding [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

```css
img {
  margin-top: 28px;
  border:5px solid #e26b34;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
```